# Detecting when a web service post has occured

Tags: windows-phone-8

I just wrote a simple windows 8 form that post to web service api. It works fine. But my challenge is been able to determine when the post operation was a success and a failure. I dont know how to return a value cos aysnc Task is not allowing a return type.

```
//This class does the post to web service 
public class B2cMobileuserService : IB2cMobileuserService
    {
        private  string RegisterUserUrl = RestfulUrl.RegisterMobileUser;
        private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();


        public async Task RegisterMobileUser(B2cMobileuserView user)
        {
            var jsonString = Serialize(user);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await _client.PostAsync(RegisterUserUrl, content);           
        }
}


//This class calls the one above

 public class WebserviceProcessor
    {
        //declaring all the service objects that would be used
        IB2cMobileuserService mobileuserService = null;

        public WebserviceProcessor() {
            mobileuserService = new B2cMobileuserService();
        }


        //This method is going to post values to the web serever
        public async void RegisterUser(B2cMobileuserView mobileuser) {
           mobileuserService.RegisterMobileUser(mobileuser);
        }


    }



//Then the code below is from my .xaml user interface that calls the class that sends to webservice

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            B2cMobileuserView user = new B2cMobileuserView();
            user.Name = name.Text;
            user.Email = email.Text;
            user.PhoneType = "Windows Mobile";
            user.BrowserType = "None";
            user.CountryName = "Nigeria";
            user.UserPhoneID = phone.Text;

            Serviceprocessor.RegisterUser(user);

            progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }


Please I dont know how to return a value cos when I try I get the error that says async method must be void. 
I need to set a way to know when the post was a success based on the return value from the web service.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure the POST was successful, call `HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode`:

```
public async Task RegisterMobileUser(B2cMobileuserView user)
{
  var jsonString = Serialize(user);
  var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var result = await _client.PostAsync(RegisterUserUrl, content);           
  result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

If you want to return a value, use a `Task<T>` return type instead of `Task`.

On a side note, avoid `async void`; use `async Task` instead of `async void` unless the compiler *forces* you to write `async void`:

```
//This method is going to post values to the web serever
public Task RegisterUser(B2cMobileuserView mobileuser) {
  return mobileuserService.RegisterMobileUser(mobileuser);
}
```

Also, you should name your asynchronous methods ending in `*Async`:

```
//This method is going to post values to the web serever
public Task RegisterUserAsync(B2cMobileuserView mobileuser) {
  return mobileuserService.RegisterMobileUserAsync(mobileuser);
}
```

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [MSDN article on `async` best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) helpful.

Comment: Please help me here. am i return Task<HttpResponseMessage> like this. Or can you give me a sample method. for return and testing

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really appreciate. Just need a sample

Comment: You can return whatever you want. I think it would make the most sense to parse out the server response and return something more meaningful than an `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: I have done that. I read the post. My challenge now is I can not call the method in the button event handler. It says await operator can only be used in an asyc method.

Comment: An event handler can be `async void`.

Comment: should I put an async in the button event handler method.

Comment: Would that be a right thing to do. Just wana do it the right way

Comment: Yes. An event handler can be `async void`.